# golang: Getting string from []byte

Tags: go

I'm new to go (coming from the C++ world)

I've created a new writer, which "inherits" from io.writer:

```
type httpWriter struct {
  io.Writer
}
```

Next I've implemented the Write() function of the io.Writer interface:

```
func (w *httpWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err, error){...}
```

Then, I've redirected all output to that writer.

I'm having truble to print the actual string in the Write() implementation.
I've tried all string formatting I could find in the documentation, but none of them give me the original string as an output.

```
fmt.Printf("%s\n",p) \\etc..
```

Would appreciate assistance

Comment: The simplest approach is to just `string(p)`, which will convert the `[]byte` into a `string` - with the caveat that not all bytes are guaranteed to be valid UTF-8 characters (runes). Also note that `http.ResponseWriter` exists as well, which also satisfies `io.Writer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, two things:

1. You haven't "inherited" `io.Writer` (you simply stated that your struct contains a writer). In go, interfaces are implicit. If your struct implements `Write(p []byte) (n int, err, error)`, it is an `io.Writer` and can be used with any function accepting it. Period. No need to declare anything.
2. As for your problem: `fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(p))`

Comment: `string(p)` is not needed, `fmt.Printf("%s\n", p)` should work as intended.